# How to install "oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall" on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0 (Maipo)

Tags: oracle

```
This is what I get when trying to install:

[root@ilorafraud3 yum.repos.d]# **yum install oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall -y**

Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, subscription-manager
```

This system is registered to Red Hat Subscription Management, but is not receiving updates. You can use subscription-manager to assign subscriptions.
Resolving Dependencies

```
--> Running transaction check
---> Package oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall.x86_64 0:1.0-13.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-uek for package: oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall-1.0-13.el6.x86_64    
--> Processing Dependency: ksh for package: oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall-1.0-13.el6.x86_64    
--> Processing Dependency: libaio-devel for package: oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall-1.0-13.el6.x86_64   
--> Processing Dependency: compat-libstdc++-33 for package: oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall-1.0-13.el6.x86_64   
--> Running transaction check
---> Package compat-libstdc++-33.x86_64 0:3.2.3-69.el6 will be installed   
---> Package kernel-uek.x86_64 0:2.6.39-400.250.6.el6uek will be installed   
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-uek-firmware = 2.6.39-400.250.6.el6uek for package: kernel-uek-2.6.39-400.250.6.el6uek.x86_64   
--> Processing Dependency: ql23xx-firmware for package: kernel-uek-2.6.39-400.250.6.el6uek.x86_64   
---> Package ksh.x86_64 0:20120801-21.el6_6.3 will be installed   
---> Package libaio-devel.x86_64 0:0.3.107-10.el6 will be installed   
 --> Processing Dependency: libaio = 0.3.107-10.el6 for package: libaio-devel-0.3.107-10.el6.x86_64   
--> Running transaction check   
---> Package kernel-uek-firmware.noarch 0:2.6.39-400.250.6.el6uek will be installed   
---> Package libaio.i686 0:0.3.107-10.el6 will be installed   
---> Package ql23xx-firmware.noarch 0:3.03.27-3.1.el6 will be installed
```

Removing ql23xx-firmware.noarch 0:3.03.27-3.1.el6 - u due to obsoletes from installed linux-firmware-20140213-0.3.git4164c23.el7.noarch
    --> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package ql23xx-firmware.noarch 0:3.03.27-3.1.el6 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: ql23xx-firmware for package: kernel-uek-2.6.39-400.250.6.el6uek.x86_64
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
**Error: Package: kernel-uek-2.6.39-400.250.6.el6uek.x86_64 (ol6_UEK_latest)
           Requires: ql23xx-firmware**
     You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
     You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
     [root@ilorafraud3 yum.repos.d]#

Comment: I'm having this problem as well, using `--skip-broken` worked but I'm afraid that will cause me problems down the road

Answer (score 0):

What really worked, in a clean (and safe) way, for me was to rebuild the original source RPM **without** the `kernel-uek` requirement:

```
[mockbuild@eb1ts-ora04 SPECS]$ diff oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall.spec oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall.spec.orig
24c24
< #Requires:kernel-uek
---
> Requires:kernel-uek
```

All the credit should got to *[flashdba](https://flashdba.com)* for all details and possible alternative ways explained here:
https://flashdba.com/install-cookbooks/using-oracle-preinstall-rpm-with-red-hat-6/

You can find the Oracle RPMs in the links below:

- OL6: https://oss.oracle.com/ol6/SRPMS-updates/
- OL7: https://oss.oracle.com/ol7/SRPMS-updates/